# I've been a big fan of Revo Uninstaller for years now, but just upgraded to Windows 7 and saw that it is not supported. What do I do?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, revo-uninstaller

Can I still use Revo Uninstaller with Windows 7 64-bit? I saw on the Revo site that this is not necessarily supported, so I don't want to have it messing with my registry without getting some advice first. If not Revo, what is the best way to uninstall in Windows 7?

Comment: Using the built in uninstaller, which works pretty fine.

Comment: I heard from Revo that they are working on a 64bit version they hope to have released next month.  I, too, was disappointed when I loaded W7 64bit and figured out that Revo doesn't work with it.  Glary Utilites, recommended by thegreyspot, is also a great tool.  The Bulk uninstall feature is awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried Revo under 64 bit? I use it all the time on 64 bit Windows 7 and it hasn't ever given an error or failed to uninstall anything. The only thing I noticed is that a few things don't show up in Revo's list to uninstall, but they are present in Programs and Features. I'd say give it a try, I've used it at least a couple times a week for the past few months and haven't broken anything. My guess is that they maybe just didn't have a 64 bit machine to test on.

Comment: I'm still very news to Windows 7 (just installed 2 days ago) - is Programs and Features where you go now to uninstall within the Control Panel?

Comment: Yes it is, I believe it was first renamed that with Vista. I could be wrong though, as I didn't use Vista very long.

Answer (score 4):

I like [Glary Tools](http://www.glaryutilities.com/) too. It will scan for left over if it needs too. I think revo is a better at it, but Glary tools is a great alternative, in addition it has many other great tools (Bulk uninstall:)). Oh and its free.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Windows 7 that isn't supported by Revo, it's all 64-bit operating systems. I've used Revo on Windows 7 32-bit without problems, likely due to a very similar code base between it and Vista. [Total Uninstall](http://www.martau.com/) does a pretty good job for 64-bit operating systems, the only thing is that it must be installed **prior to other software** as it monitors for all system changes during installs to make an accurate and more complete uninstall. It's free for 30 days, but it doesn't cost [too much to buy](http://www.martau.com/tu_buy_now.php). [Your Uninstaller!](http://www.ursoftware.com/order.php) is also another popular commercial choice. Both tools are great, unfortunately there aren't many good freeware alternatives for 64-bit systems yet to my knowledge.